# Facebook api with Xamarin

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, xamarin

I am creating an application by Xamarin (andoroid / iOS) and would log in using facebook, and I do so by sharing the same access code?

Comment: Could you edit your Q to be more specific about what you are trying to do and what you have tried (code)?

Comment: Yes of course, 
I would like to use the Facebook API to create login to my application, but I would take the same code for both Andoird as for iOS, I'm using the code below;

Comment: fb = new FacebookClient ();
   appId = "1651991695024937";//Jaques Loesch, pegando api Facebook Intent.GetStringExtra ("AppId");
   extendedPermissions = Intent.GetStringExtra ("ExtendedPermissions");
   url = GetFacebookLoginUrl (appId, extendedPermissions);

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following the code sample I've published here: https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinFormsNativeFacebook

a guide of how to do so:

Steps to set up your project:

**Installation**:

1) For Android download from nuget/Components the Facebook Android SDK: http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid and place it in your droid project.

2) For iOS download from nuget/Components the Facebook iOS SDK: http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios and place it in your iOS project.

Set up components:

Shared code set up:

1) Add a FacebookLoginButton which inherits from Button, leave it without any implementation

2) Add that button to the login page

3)Add to App.cs the following property:

```
   public static Action<string> PostSuccessFacebookAction { get; set; }
```

4) in the LoginPage.xaml.cs (or in the viewmodel class if you have one), add the navigation for this action:

```
    App.PostSuccessFacebookAction = async token =>
    {
       //you can use this token to authenticate to the server here
       //call your FacebookLoginService.LoginToServer(token)
       //I'll just navigate to a screen that displays the token:
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DiplayTokenPage(token));

    };
```

**Android**: 1) Add to strings.xml file (found at Resources/Valus) The following lines {Your App Id Here} {Your App Name}

2) Add to Manifest.xml the following code:

3) Create activity class for facebook (I called it FacebookActivity)

4) Create a custom rendrer for the facebook Login button (I called it FacebookLoginButtonRendererAndroid)

5) Add to mainActivity class The OnActionResult method to handle response from the FacebookActivity

**iPhone**:

1) In AppDelegate class, register in method FinishedLaunching the following:

FBSettings.DefaultAppID = FacebookAppId;
   FBSettings.DefaultDisplayName = FacebookAppName;

2) Override the following methods:

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
    base.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
    return FBSession.ActiveSession.HandleOpenURL(url);
}

public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
{
    base.OnActivated(application);
    // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
    // (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
    FBSession.ActiveSession.HandleDidBecomeActive();
}
```

3) Create a custom rendrer for the facebook Login button (I called it FacebookLoginButtonRendererIos)